# IntelliJ + Maven Error: Could not find or load main class root

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I am trying to use Maven (Bundled Maven 3) with an IntelliJ project (Spring). When I double click one of the Maven lifecycle steps I get the following error:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=project root "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" -Didea.launcher.port=7536 "-Didea.launcher.bin.path=C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -classpath "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.4\lib\idea_rt.jar" com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=14.1.4 clean
>
> Error: Could not find or load main class root

Screenshot: [image]

I have searched both Google and StackOverflow for several hours but didn't find a solution for the problem.

I'm just starting to use Maven so I don't know a whole lot about it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem was a space in one of the IntelliJ Maven settings.
In the Build Tools > Maven > Runner section I changed VM Options from

-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=project root

to

-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory="project root"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I try everything what I found. This solution weren't described anywhere:
Go to: Run->Edit Configurations-> CHANGE "Use classpath of module" to different one. 
It resolved problem for me.